# Is there a way to search in Dictionary<int[], List<int> by values inside values faster than this code already does?

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, search, data-structures

I have Dictionary in which i need to search for value inside of List faster than i do for now.
List is always sorted.
I need to find key that has a value which contains speciffic int to return an int from the key array at index that i pass in method.

I tried some tips from stackoverflow :)
And also because Lists are always sorted i added binary search but it still doesn't work fast enough.
And got code shown down below.
It works but i really need to do it faster.

```
Dictionary<int[], List<int>> Commits { get; set; }
```

```
Commits = new Dictionary<int[], List<int>>(new MyEqualityComparer());
```

```
public int Checkout(int commitNumber, int fileNumber)
{
    if (commitNumber >= CommitsCount)
        throw new ArgumentException();
    else
       {
         var k = Commits.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value.BinarySearch(commitNumber) > -1).Key; // Here's the problem
         return k[fileNumber];
       }
}
```

I think some other data structures might help me to store `int[]` and 'List' more efficient or some other ways to find that key.
I hope i explained my problem properly.

Comment: Well, binary search is `O(Log(N))` which is obviously pretty fast already. But why are you using a custom comparer to compare the `int` values rather than the default one? What does the implementation of `MyEqualityComparer` look like? Perhaps that's a bit slow. Otherwise, instead of `List<int>` maybe you could use `HashSet<int>` which has an `O(N)` lookup, although I suspect that's still not going to be fast enough...

Comment: @MatthewWatson i use `MyEqualityComparer` to use `ContainsKey()' method.

Comment: Oh yes, I see that now. That's not likely to be the issue then.

Comment: @Matthew O(N) lookup? Might as well stick with the list then :)

Comment: @MatthewWatson i can't use any sets because i need to extract value from that value at index that i'm interested in. I didn't mention it earlier so i'm sorry, i'll edit the question.

Comment: @Funk OOPS typo, obviously I  mean O(1). :)

Comment: "List is always sorted." your list or is that a, invalid general concept you have? reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.sortedlist?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss sorry i didn't clearly get you but i'll say that lists are always sorted because of the way they are being filled. I just store commit numbers in them and commit number n cannot be stored before commit number m (for any m < n). So these lists are always sorted

Comment: It would really be nice if we had names for the `int[]`, the `List<int>`, each `int` in both... and some sample data...

Comment: Without sufficient information behind what and why, this really feels like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a `Dictionary<(int commitNumber, int fileNumber), int>` instead.

The key would be a tuple made out of the commitNumber and fileNumber, and then use TryGetValue on it. It would be considerably faster.

**IMPORTANT:** You do need an EqualityComparer to compare the tuples.

The code would look like this:

```
Dictionary<(int commitNumber, int fileNumber), int> Commits { get; set; }
Commits = new Dictionary<(int commitNumber, int fileNumber), int>(new MyEqualityComparer());

public int Checkout(int commitNumber, int fileNumber)
{
    if (commitNumber >= CommitsCount) // not sure you even need this now
        throw new ArgumentException();
    if (Commits.TryGetValue((commitNumber, fileNumber), out int output))
        return output;
    throw new ArgumentException($"The combination of commit number {commitNumber} and file number {fileNumber} was not found.");
}
```

Comment: This method might be faster but this way i'll have to store each int (file) so i get out of memory. In my code i stored int[] (files) and list of their commit numbers. So i wouldn't store same ints over and over again. Is there a way to avoid it using your solution?

Comment: Well, if you want to work with a hierarchy of sorts, perhaps you could consider having a `Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, int>>` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Lacking a description for the data, let's name them:

```
// let's call int[] filesizes indexed by fileNumber
// let's call int in List<int> the commitNumber

// then, let's use Dictionary<commitNumber, filesizes[]> as the data structure
```

So, now we can re-write `Checkout`:

```
Dictionary<int, int[]> CommitNumberToFilesizes = new Dictionary<int, int[]>();

public int Checkout(int commitNumber, int fileNumber) {
    if (commitNumber >= CommitsCount)
        throw new ArgumentException();
    else {
        var filesizes = CommitNumberToFilesizes[commitNumber];
        return filesizes[fileNumber];
    }
}
```

Without knowing how you get the original data, I can't say how much effort would be required to create this structure.

Since you are trying to speed up `Checkout`, I assume you call it a lot more than you add/get the data behind it.